# Modifying custom list obtained by tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I have used the tocloft package for creating a custom list of a bunch of abstracts for a conference programm book. In my real world problem there the numbers in front of the contentlines are equally redundant as here in the example.

1) How to get rid of the numbers in front of the "chapters"? [SOLVED]

In the example picture you can see that the list of abstract is fairly confusing. I think it will look better if one could devide one content line into two lines:

> Author primus 
>   First abstract title for conference on NTPNTTSP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
>   authorus secundus, authorus tertius
>   second abstract title that could be horrendous long because participants don't really care. . . . 2

2) How to break tableofcontentlike lines into two?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listexamplename}{Abstracts}
\newlistof{customchapter}{cc}{\listexamplename}

\newcommand{\customchapter}[1]
{%
   \refstepcounter{customchapter}
   \addcontentsline{cc}{customchapter}
{\protect\numberline{\thecustomchapter}#1}\par
}

\begin{document}

\listofcustomchapter

\customchapter{authorus primus -- First abstract title for conference on NTPNTTSP}
\null\newpage

\customchapter{authorus secundus, authorus tertius -- second abstract title that could be horrendous long because of participants don't really care}
\null\newpage


\customchapter{authorus quartus -- not giving f. anyway}
\null\newpage 

\end{document}
```

Comment: For number (1), have you checked what happens if you do not include `\numberline` in that definition?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't help. In fact due to your comment, I tried it again plus removing the `{\thecustomchapter}`. Now the numbers are gone.  I don't know why I did not consider this before.

Comment: `\numberline` takes an argument, so you should remove that as well.

Comment: Oh, yes I did so, but forgot to mention it in the comment above. With the `\numberline{}` command still there, one gets a ugly vertical line with the first letters of the authors

Comment: Yes, `\numberline{...}` sets its contents in a box of a certain width. If you do not want this indentation, remove `\numberline{...}`

Comment: I already did. Thank you.